# get stale body on OkHttp 2.0

Tags: java, caching, okhttp

My webservice sends these headers:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, max-stale=86400
```

Now on my first call, this is the response:

1. code = 200
2. cacheResponse = null
3. networkResponse = Response{code=200, ...}
4. body = correctdata

The second call within a minute is:

1. code = 200
2. cacheResponse = Response{code=200, ...}
3. networkResponse = null
4. body = correctdata

Now, after a minute, I delete my webservice, and do another call. Now because of the max-stale header, I expect to be able to retrieve the cacheResponse, to show the old data.
The response is this:

1. code = 404
2. cacheResponse = Response{code=200, ...}
3. networkResponse = Response{code=404, ...}
4. body = pagenotfounditem

Now the cacheResponse.body() returns null, so I can't use the old data, so crashes on           `String cb = cacheBody.string();`. A code sample is shown below:

```
        if(response.networkResponse() != null) {
            System.out.println("There is no cache, or cache is invalidated.");
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Call is not successful");
                if(response.cacheResponse() != null) {
                    System.out.println("There is a cache");
                    ResponseBody cacheBody = response.cacheResponse().body();
                    String cb = cacheBody.string();
                    System.out.println("cacheBody: " + cb); 
                    return cb;
                }
            }

        }
        ResponseBody body = response.body();
        if(body != null) {
            String b = body.string();
            System.out.println("body: " + b); 
            return b;               
        }
```

Is this behaviour intended, and if so, how can I get the cached response data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this request header:

```
Cache-Control: max-stale=86400
```

That'll cause OkHttp to use the cache only.

Comment: The key here was it should be a *request* header, not a response header.